# How to split a list\array according to some related values into 3 lists

Tags: python, list, numpy, plot

I have python homework which asks me to plot current-time and voltage-time graphs according to given values. Values of time are in decimals; However values of voltage and current are binaries. All values are stored in a text file I have to import them from. I know how graph them but I don't know how to split time values, current values, and voltage values into 3 lists. Also I don't know which code I should write to change from binary to integer and to determine the sign of each of them.  The leftmost digit of the current, voltage binary values determines the sign of the value, if digit=0 then it is positive, if digit=1 then it is negative.

I have tried:

```
import numpy as np

t = []
I = []
v = []

with open("rawdata.txt") as DATA:
    data_ = [line.split() for line in DATA]
    data = np.array(data_)
    print(data[:,0])
```

I have tried the last line's cod to print just values of time but it did not work.

**Edit: Error message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Users\mustafa ghanım\Desktop\İTÜ - BAHAR 2016 DÖNEMİ\PYTHON\Proje\proje.py", line 5, in <module> print(data[:,0]) 
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

---

```
 current=[];voltage=[];import numpy as np
 with open("rawdata.txt") as DATA:
 data_=[line.split()for line in DATA if not line.isspace()]
 data=np.array(data_)
 t=data[1:,0]
 I=data[1:,1]
 v=data[1:,2]
 print ("Time:",t)
 print (I)
 print (v)
 for i in I:
     d_c=int(i,2)
     current.append(d_c)
 print("Current:",current)
 for j in v:
    d_v=int(j,2)
    voltage.append(d_v)
print("Voltage",voltage)
```

Sorry for my late responding, I am trying now to export my new decimal values which I have constructed list foe each of them (values of time,voltage,current,power) as decimals. I am asked now to export these values as a table which will include rows and columns of course to a text file called "powdata.txt"..any idea for which code should I use?!
I have tried to write:

```
 powdata=open("powdata.txt","w")
 for a in t:
   powdata.write("%s\n"%a)
 for b in current:
 "and so on!"

 powdata.close()
```

Unfortunately this kind of codes just  writes data in the text file vertically I mean not like the suggested table. 
Unfortunately this kind of codes just  writes data in the text file vertically I mean not like the suggested table.

```
          time(s) voltage(V)    current(A)
           0    0000000000      101101010
           0.0005   0000110001  101011000
          0.001 0001100000      101011000
```

such a table must be written in the new file.

Comment: ok, so if it didn't "work" what did it do? Without a traceback message or a sample of the file there is no way I (or anyone else who would be capable of helping you) would be able to guess what went wrong.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mustafa ghanım\Desktop\İTÜ - BAHAR 2016 DÖNEMİ\PYTHON\Proje\proje.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(data[:,0])
IndexError: too many indices for array.............
"I have this error message"..

Comment: ok, which means that your data was not a perfect grid (same number of words/numbers on each line) maybe there are just some lines that are just whitespace, you could try `[line.split() for line in DATA` **`if not line.isspace()`** `]` but I'm not sure that really helps you with splitting it up into three lists...

Comment: Thanks! it worked now, do you have any idea about converting binaries to decimals with considering the sign..?

Comment: well the sign aside I think [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) will do all you need if you specify `base=2` something like this: `int('100101',base=2) -> 37` then I guess you could just cut off the first one and treat it differently for the sign.

Comment: I do not know what kind of functions should  I write to make the program be able to differentiate between signs digit and the other ones so that the program can calculate them correctly.. the new codes I added convert all binary digits to decimals without differentiating them.

Comment: I may have missed it, but did you show data that is binary?  Is it two's complement format? or does it start with - if negative?

Comment: `def parse_signed_int(s):  if s[0] == '1': s = "-"+s[1:]  ; return int(s,base=2)` It is literally that easy. (note you do the `return` either way)

Comment: Can you post a few lines from rawdata.txt?